# Custom TeamSpeak IP no longer working after adding SSL

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, a-records, teamspeak, certbot

I am currently using CloudFlare and recently added an SSL certificate to my script.

Before hand, I added an A record (proxied with CloudFlare) that pointed to my TS IP. It worked like this: ts.domain.net:PORT

However, after I added the SSL cert, it doesn't seem to work anymore.

If it matters, my main site IP is also (of course) proxied under CloudFlare

Thanks!

Comment: Is the certificate issued for "ts.domain.net"? Is it a self-signed or a real certificate issued by a common CA?

Comment: @Robert HTTPS is enabled and working great. It's signed with a "Let's Encrypt" certificate from [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org)

Comment: @Robert Oh sorry, just re-read what you said. No, its only issues for mydomain.net  -  Do you I need to get a different certification for TS.mydomain.net? Thanks.

Comment: Of course. The DNS name must match exact one of the Subject Alternative Names in the certificate, as long as you don't have a wildcard certificate. Wildcard certificates can be easily identified as they have a SAN like `*.mydomain.net`.

Comment: @Robert. Ah, I see. Thank you! I guess you could reply as an answer or some sort so I can up vote and select it as the answer? Will try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every certificate contains one or more Subject Alternative Names. You can use the certificate only on domains that are listed as SAN within the certificate, as long as you don't have  a wildcard certificate that can be used on a all subdomain, eg. `*.mydomain.net`.

Therefore for your TS server you need a certificate that contains the SAN `ts.domain.net`. If your current certificate is only for `domain.net` you need another certificate for your Teamspeak subdomain.